# Intelij extract method keeps trying to replace duplicate method signatures - please stop

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij has a really neat feature, that lets me seamlessly extract a block of code into its own method. I can then give this method a nice, descriptive name and move on with life.

However, intellij also tries to find *other* blocks of code that are similar, and then tries to perusade me that I should also refactor *them* too, to use this new method its made. And then, when I hit the oddly-named "cancel" button (which implies the whole operation is cancelled, but it's not, it just stops asking about any remaining blocks), it leaves me looking at whatever the block of code it last asked me about.

I really don't like this feature. Here's why: If I'm say comparing two ints - the naming of the code block will depend on the context of those two ints, but intellij will find *any* comparison between two ints anywhere in that file, and then insist that this is also a candidate for extraction.

Most times it is not, and to make it worse, when I ask intellij to stop it, in a fit of pique, leaves me wherever the last comparison was, so now I have to navigate back to where I was working.

How do I tell intellij just to extract exactly what I selected, and do nothing else?

Comment: Can you please share the code sample you experience the issue with and the idea.log file (Help | Show Log in Finder). Thank you

Comment: what? it's not an "issue" it's an easily replicable event. this doesn't need a code sample and a code log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow/vote/comment the issue created for this usability problem at YouTrack:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233201